# Which is faster: calling mysql in a loop, or looping through a single result set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am processing a table and making frequent calls to mysql database like inside a forloop

First thing,, MY MYSQL Table is tooooooooo biGGGGGG

I am calling

```
    for ($i=0; $i < count($pages); $i++) {
        array_push($views, $this->get_page_views($domain, $pages[$i]));
    } // get_page_views is a function where i select data from table accourding to page
```

I think i should not do that much call to database or should i use

```
//selecting all rows and coloumns and then i should process them through php
//select * from page views 
//and process them independently
```

My question is which is best

Comment: show the DB code and which way your accessing SQL PDO or Normal ?

Comment: The best is to write code that's maintainable, that works and that's resilient. Yours appears to be none of that. And also, you haven't included the relevant parts, but I would bet you're opening and closing connections in that loop.

Comment: i have updated check it i am not closing connection in a loop

Comment: Your second suggestion is the best. Calling MySQL is expensive, processing data in a loop, however, is not.

Comment: "calling mysql in a loop"? e.g. a seperate query for each loop iteration? that's hideously inefficient compared to running one query and looping on the result set. it's like driving to the store, buying an apple, driving home. then driving to the store again, buying bread, driving home. then driving to the storage again to buy butter, yada yada yada. Instead, you should drive to the store, buy all of your groceries, and then sort them out at home.

Comment: My mysql table is too big then???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what your code is doing exactly, but if your loop is opening a new connection on every iteration, that's really inefficient. Your client code ought to be written to minimise the number of times it needs to hit the database, and if it needs to make lots of queries in a short space of time, it should open a connection, make the queries, and then close the connection.

At a guess, from the limited information going, you could even do it in one query, which is even better. Usually a loop with a query for each iteration is a sign that something needs refactoring to a single query.

And I seriously doubt that your MySQL table is "tooooooooo biGGGGGG". It should be able to handle tens of millions of rows comfortably, if you've got the right indexes on the right fields. If it's performing badly, then one of the following is very likely true:

1. you haven't sorted out your indexes properly;
2. you are writing inefficient queries (as discussed above);
3. you haven't structured your data properly (unnormalised, etc.);
4. you have ten rows for every person on the planet.

Comment: See, Its a analytics system, I provide full detail to user user about his domain,,, so should i select all rows of that domain
or
i should make call to just what i need

Comment: @NaveenSinghraghuvanshi your other aim should be to avoid unnecessary network traffic, so if you can retrieve exactly what you need and no more, then do that. Get the database to do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Making a connection and closing, in a loop is not a good idea when the table to processed is already known or static.

In that case, you can run the query once and store the result in an array (if it is php) or in a ResultSet (if it where Java) or you can use collections like HashMap or Dictionary and process them.

The idea is to cache the results before for improved performance.